# pandas AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'view'

Tags: python, pandas

This is a killer problem that probably has a simple solution for a pandas newbie like me:

I'm trying to replace one record of pandas DataFrame (df) with the latest version of that label (found in a separate DataFrame (latest_version).

```
df.ix[label] = latest_version.ix[label]
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'view'
```

df itself is large and complex (and proprietary) so I'd like to avoid posting it if I can; I'm hoping there's something easy I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: output of df.info() and latest_version.info()

```
ipdb> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 7 entries, A to G
Data columns (total 73 columns):
Column 0   7 non-null object
Column 1   7 non-null object
Column 2   7 non-null object
Column 3   7 non-null object
Column 4   7 non-null object
Column 5   7 non-null float64
Column 6   1 non-null object
Column 7   7 non-null object
Column 8   7 non-null object
Column 9   6 non-null datetime64[ns]
Column 10  0 non-null object
Column 11  0 non-null object
Column 12  5 non-null object
Column 13  0 non-null object
Column 14  0 non-null object
Column 15  6 non-null datetime64[ns]
Column 16  0 non-null object
Column 17  0 non-null object
Column 18  0 non-null object
Column 19  0 non-null object
Column 20  0 non-null object
Column 21  0 non-null object
Column 22  0 non-null object
Column 23  0 non-null object
Column 24  0 non-null object
Column 25  0 non-null object
Column 26  0 non-null object
Column 27  0 non-null object
Column 28  0 non-null object
Column 29  0 non-null object
Column 30  0 non-null object
Column 31  0 non-null object
Column 32  0 non-null object
Column 33  0 non-null object
Column 34  0 non-null object
Column 35  0 non-null object
Column 36  0 non-null object
Column 37  4 non-null object
Column 38  6 non-null object
Column 39  4 non-null object
Column 40  0 non-null object
Column 41  0 non-null object
Column 42  0 non-null object
Column 43  6 non-null object
Column 44  0 non-null object
Column 45  6 non-null object
Column 46  0 non-null object
Column 47  4 non-null object
Column 48  0 non-null object
Column 49  4 non-null object
Column 50  0 non-null object
Column 51  0 non-null object
Column 52  0 non-null object
Column 53  0 non-null object
Column 54  0 non-null object
Column 55  0 non-null object
Column 56  0 non-null object
Column 57  0 non-null object
Column 58  0 non-null object
Column 59  0 non-null object
Column 60  0 non-null object
Column 61  0 non-null object
Column 62  0 non-null object
Column 63  0 non-null object
Column 64  0 non-null object
Column 65  0 non-null object
Column 66  0 non-null object
Column 67  0 non-null object
Column 68  0 non-null object
Column 69  0 non-null object
Column 70  0 non-null object
Column 71  0 non-null object
Column 72  0 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), object(70)ipdb> 

ipdb> latest_version.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4 entries, A to D
Data columns (total 73 columns):
Column 0   4 non-null object
Column 1   4 non-null object
Column 2   4 non-null object
Column 3   4 non-null object
Column 4   4 non-null object
Column 5   4 non-null int64
Column 6   4 non-null object
Column 7   4 non-null object
Column 8   4 non-null object
Column 9   4 non-null object
Column 10  4 non-null object
Column 11  4 non-null object
Column 12  4 non-null object
Column 13  4 non-null object
Column 14  4 non-null object
Column 15  4 non-null object
Column 16  3 non-null object
Column 17  4 non-null object
Column 18  4 non-null object
Column 19  4 non-null object
Column 20  3 non-null object
Column 21  3 non-null object
Column 22  4 non-null object
Column 23  4 non-null object
Column 24  4 non-null object
Column 25  4 non-null object
Column 26  4 non-null object
Column 27  4 non-null object
Column 28  4 non-null object
Column 29  4 non-null object
Column 30  4 non-null object
Column 31  4 non-null object
Column 32  4 non-null object
Column 33  4 non-null object
Column 34  4 non-null object
Column 35  4 non-null object
Column 36  4 non-null object
Column 37  4 non-null object
Column 38  4 non-null object
Column 39  4 non-null object
Column 40  4 non-null object
Column 41  4 non-null object
Column 42  4 non-null object
Column 43  4 non-null object
Column 44  4 non-null object
Column 45  4 non-null float64
Column 46  4 non-null object
Column 47  4 non-null object
Column 48  4 non-null object
Column 49  4 non-null object
Column 50  4 non-null object
Column 51  4 non-null object
Column 52  4 non-null object
Column 53  4 non-null object
Column 54  4 non-null object
Column 55  4 non-null object
Column 56  1 non-null object
Column 57  1 non-null object
Column 58  4 non-null object
Column 59  4 non-null object
Column 60  4 non-null object
Column 61  4 non-null object
Column 62  4 non-null object
Column 63  4 non-null object
Column 64  4 non-null object
Column 65  4 non-null object
Column 66  4 non-null object
Column 67  4 non-null object
Column 68  4 non-null object
Column 69  4 non-null object
Column 70  4 non-null object
Column 71  4 non-null object
Column 72  4 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(71)ipdb>
```

Further edit (in response to Ed): Here are the tables with just the columns that have different types:

```
ipdb> latest_version.ix[:,[5,9,15]]
                                    line_number  entry_date entry_ref_a
unique_index                                                           
NEW/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                       0  2014-12-30  2015-01-14
NEW/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB                       1  2014-12-30            
NEW/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC                       2  2014-12-30            
ipdb>/df.ix[:,[5,9,15]]
                                    line_number           entry_date  \
unique_index                                                           
OLD/204442                                    0  1419897600000000000   
OLD/343278                                    1  1419897600000000000   
OLD/359628                                    2  1419897600000000000   
NEW/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                       0           2014-12-30   

                                            entry_ref_a  
unique_index                                             
OLD/204442                          1421193600000000000  
OLD/343278                          1421193600000000000  
OLD/359628                          1422230400000000000  
NEW/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                      2015-01-14
```

Definitely lends credence to the idea that there's a type mismatch issue here...

Comment: What is `label`, does it work if you pass the string of the label?

Comment: Please post the output from `df.info()` and `latest_version.info()`

Comment: label is a unicode that identifies the row. It does NOT work if I pass str(label). (I get the same error.) I've added the output you requested above. Thank you very much for taking a look at it.

Comment: Can you post a single line of raw data for both dfs so I can try to recreate your problem, something I have noticed is that the dtypes of both dfs are not the same for instance `df` has :`dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), object(70)` whilst `latest_version` is :`dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(71)`, I think you need the dtypes to match in order to perform direct assignment, can you check your column's to see if you haven't converted a couple to datetime64, thanks

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I'll try to find a line of raw data (which is financial information and hence why I'm being careful here) to get comfortable posting it. In the mean time, is there a better way (than direct assignment) to accomplish the objective?

Comment: That is the correct method just that you may be trying to coerce data into incompatible dtypes, i'd look at the columns that are different dtypes and see if you can fix those up

Comment: Thanks, Ed; just added the data...I'll try coercing the "OLD" to strings perhaps.

Comment: Ed, this worked. Feel free to add an answer and I'll 'check' it.

Comment: Sorry what worked exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem here seems to be that you had a mismatch on the dtypes between the 2 dfs you were trying to assign to and from:

```
df dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), object(70)
```

whilst

```
latest_version is :dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(71)
```

From the output we can see that that columns that clash some are datetimes, whilst they are int64's in the corresponding column in the other df.

You can convert the ill-formed columns to datetime by doing:

```
df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date')
```

and likewise for `entry_ref_a`