# Assigning functions to drop drown elements in python dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created a dashboard to display data in CSV's. However i am not sure how to assign separate functions to relative drop down options. Below is the code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df1 = pd.read_csv('ReturnsData - returns_summary.csv.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('ReturnsData - NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('ReturnsData - AllReturns.csv.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('ReturnsData - OrderCreationdetails.csv.csv')
df5 = pd.read_csv('ReturnsData - Return_guideid_counts.csv.csv')


def generate_table(dataframe,max_rows=1000000):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label' : 'Returns Summary' , 'value' : 'df1'},
            {'label' : 'NonReturn guideid counts' , 'value' : 'df2'}
        ],
        # value='df1'
        # multi = True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return generate_table(df1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here out of the two options i can only trigger the function to display df1. How do i trigger df2 when second drop down is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You have hard-coded `df1` in your `generate_table` method. You need to make this method's parameter dynamic, depending on what `value` is passed through the `update_output` method of the callback (this is what the user chooses from the dropdown). Following the example from the [official Dash-Plotly docks](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/dropdown) you need to modify your code this way:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return generate_table(value)
```

If you need to use different functions for `df1` and `df2` you could add this logic:

```
def update_output(value):
    if value == df1:
        return generate_table(value)
    elif value == df2:
        return other_generate_table_function(value)
```

Comment: I have tried the same but it is giving error :   File "/Users/soubhik.b/PycharmProjects/Dash_Tutorial/app2.py", line 55, in update_output
    return generate_table(value)
  File "/Users/soubhik.b/PycharmProjects/Dash_Tutorial/app2.py", line 20, in generate_table
    [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: Well, then that's an entirely different problem related to your dataframes and not Dash - apparently you're trying to assign to and from dfs with different dtypes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523324/pandas-attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-view#answers-header) may give you some hints. Just to be sure, I checked my solution with just printing text instead of generating tables and it worked, so once you fix the dataframes this should work fine.